# Android Compose Jetpack Autofocus on TextField when screen open or programmatically on application requirement

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am using android compose jetpack version "0.1.0-dev14". According to application requirement, I want to auto focus TextField once screen is visible. and another scenario is like I want to focus next TextField in same screen on next ImeAction.Next action. I could not find any method or solution for this problem. If Anyone can help me to sole this problem, It will be really appreciated.

Thank you..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This sample](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:ui/ui-text/integration-tests/ui-text-compose-demos/src/main/java/androidx/ui/text/demos/ComposeInputFieldFocusTransition.kt) shows how to request focus on the next view.

To achieve autofocus on first view on the screen, I believe this can be used:

```
// ... composable context...

onActive(callback = {
    focusModifiers.first().requestFocus()
})

// ... composable context...
```

Answer (score 6):

With `1.0.0` to achieve autofocus you can use:

```
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
    onDispose { }
}
```

In this way the system grants focus to the component associated with this `FocusRequester`.
For example:

```
val focusRequester = FocusRequester()
TextField(
    //...
    modifier = Modifier
        // add focusRequester modifier 
        .focusRequester(focusRequester)
)
```

Comment: Nice, it works but it doesn't shift the screen up if the keyboard would cover the `TextField` unfortunately... any fix for that?

Comment: val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current and keyboardController?.show() before onDispose

Comment: why you don't remember `FocusRequester`? it should be `remember { FocusRequester() }`

Comment: if `DisposableEffect.onDispose` method isn't used then just use `LaunchedEffect` instead